# Is Correlation a linear operator? and is it a measure in terms of measure thoery?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Let X, Y be two vectors belong to $R^n$, and $X_{c}$ and $Y_{c}$ are the centered versions of X and Y. Cov(X,Y) = $\frac{<X-\bar{X}, Y-\bar{Y}>}{n-1}$ and Corr(X,Y) = $\frac{<X_{c},Y_{c}>}{||X_{c}||*||Y_{c}||}$. Is corr a linear operator in terms of algebra? and Is corr a measure in terms of measure theory? And how to verify that?
Comparing 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 of corr, does the difference between 0.1 and 0.5 and the difference between 0.5 and 0.9 tell the same magnitude of difference in the correlation of data?

Answer (score 2):

- For any positive scalar $c$, you have $\text{Corr}(cX, Y) = \text{Corr}(X,Y)$.
- Your definition of correlation is a function that takes two vectors and returns a number. A measure takes in sets and returns a nonnegative number.
- I don't know what you mean by "same magnitude of difference," but I will mention the following. You can think of your correlation as the cosine of the angle between $X_c$ and $Y_c$. So a cosine value of $0.1$ and $0.5$ and $0.9$ corresponds respectively to angles of $84$, $60$, and $26$ degrees. So in terms of looking at the angles, the differences are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Say I've got n random samples for population (X, Y) and I randomly divide them into two subgroups, suppose the corr(X, Y) = a, what could possibly the sample correlations be in the sub sample? Will summing the correlations obtained from subgroups reflect the actual correlation?

Comment: @HotPizza I think anything can happen. For example, you can come up with an example where one group is a cluster of points near $(1,1)$, and another group is a cluster near $(-1, -1)$, such that each group's correlation is $0$ while the entire group's correlation is strictly positive.